# Why does my tag filter on "lotus*" show questions on Hanami?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-filters

I have a tag filter set up on "lotus*", in order to see all questions related to [HCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCL_Domino) or [Lotus Notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCL_Domino).

I indeed get questions with the word Lotus, but I also receive [Hanami](https://github.com/davydovanton/lotus) questions.

Why is this the case, and how can I fix it?

Comment: [GitHub, davydovanton /lotus](https://github.com/davydovanton/lotus): *"Hanami ... This project was formerly known as Lotus"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this is about [Stack Exchange Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) which also considers tag synonyms.

Example filter: [Questions tagged [lotus*] which is also [hanami]](https://stackexchange.com/filters/436485/questions-tagged-lotus-which-is-also-hanami)

[image]

Note that as [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419797/2821954) has explained, [lotusrb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotusrb) is a synonym of [hanami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hanami) on Stack Overflow, thus it also includes Hanami questions from Stack Overflow.

This is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285698/241919) that Stack Exchange Filtered Questions include tag synonyms

> This is by-design: When filtering by tags, synonyms are taken into account.

*Whether it is a correct synonym or not, it is another question*.

Answer (score 4):

[lotusrb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotusrb) is a synonym of [hanami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hanami), as can been seen on the [tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hanami/synonyms):

[image]

However, when I [search for](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blotus*%5D&searchOn=1) or create a filter on [tag:lotus*], that expands into

> [lotus-notes] or [lotus-domino] or [lotusscript] or [lotus] or [lotus-formula] or [lotus-wcm] or [lotus-designer]

and I don't see any [hanami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hanami) questions?

Comment: Thanks. I had never heard of Hanami before, nor lotusrb. And yes, sorry, Andrew T is correct, a Stack Exchange question filter.